# Variables in template files

Tags: theming

In my `.tpl.php` template files, I have several links and names of external websites. I would like to print these as variables, which are defined in `template.php`. That way, if I have to change a link, I can just change it in `template.php` and have them updated in all my `tpl.php` files.

How can I do this?

### Steps I have tried

[In this tutorial](http://www.whenwhowhere.com/tech-blog/add-variable-theme-template-files-drupal-7#sthash.tYxNFcAO.dpuf), it says you can define your variables in `themename_preprocess_page(&$variables)`. You can then call them with `<?php print render($page['your_variable_name']); ?>`

However, when I try this, I  just get a message stating `Notice: Undefined variable: page in include()`. The variable also doesn't print.

Also, if I use this method, can I use my variable in all tpl.php files or just the page.tpl.php file?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18545/define-variables-for-template-files have a look at this will solve your problem

Comment: @DEVARAJJOHNSON That link works for node.tpl.php and page.tpl.php but not block.tpl.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a variable in `themename_preprocess_page(&$variables)`, it should could be accessed using the variable name itself. Example

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_new_variable'] = "String value";
  $variables['my_new_variable_array'] = array(); // Some renderable array.
}
```

And then in your template you could simply print the first variable directly

```
<?php print $my_new_variable; ?>
```

And render the renderable array using the `render()` function:

```
<?php print render($my_new_variable_array); ?>
```

**Note:** The array keys become the name of the variable, so please make sure to use a unique name to the keys.

Comment: This only seems to work in page.tpl.php file. It doesn't work in other tpl.php files (e.g. node.tpl.php).

Comment: It also doesn't work for block.tpl.php

Comment: It works for **all** theme functions @big_smile, it's the fundamental mechanism Drupal provides to add/edit variables in a template file. It works for page.tpl.php and block.tpl.php. The proof is the existence of functions like [`template_preprocess_block()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7), which core uses to do the same thing

Comment: @Clive Does that mean I need to have separate functions (e.g.  themename_preprocess_page, themename_preprocess_block, themename_preprocess_node). Isn't possible to have one function that provides the variables for all templates?

Comment: Yep, that's `hook_preprocess()`. It's fired for every theme preprocess (including page and block)